# Running Hbase on Ssds and conducting Performance evaluation

Tags: hbase

Has anyone tried running Hbase on SSDs , if yes how was the experience and if possible do share read,write other performance metrics

Answer (score 0):

I did some simple benchmarking by replaying our ingestion tests (sequential writes mostly) on AWS a few days ago. I used m3.large instances and the only difference was magnetic vs standard SSD. Throughput was 50% higher at 50K/sec per node, at which point we hit a bottleneck in another part of the application.

It might be useful to benchmark performance on the same machine just by changing data.dir between SSD and magnetic disks.

Comment: I used default values. It was a pseudo-cluster with distributed set to true.